# Inno Setup - How to display 3 options: full | upgrade | uninstall?

Tags: upgrade, inno-setup, uninstallation

I have a working setup.exe that runs 'full' and 'upgrade' installations from a proxy server that elevates the user to admin only during execution of setup.exe.
While the setup.exe successfully creates an uninstall icon, the user does not have sufficient privileges to execute an uninstall. :(
So, it is desirable and efficient for me to submit a single setup.exe to the proxy server that offers the users a single point of reference.
How can I add a 3rd selection to 'uninstall'?
My initial thoughts are to trick the [Types] section:

```
[Types]
Name: "full"; Description: "Full Install"
Name: "upg"; Description: "Upgrade Only"
Name: "del"; Description: "Uninstall"
```

But which event do I code in to start the uninstall process?
Is InitializeSetup() too early? Meaning the user hasn't selected anything yet.

EDIT: After much searching and prompts from TLama, I have something working.

```
// code snippet...
Function GetUninstallString(): String;
var
  sUnInstPath: String;
  sUnInstallString: String;
begin
  sUnInstPath := ExpandConstant('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#emit SetupSetting("AppId")}_is1');
  sUnInstallString := '';
  if not RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString) then
    RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString);
  Result := sUnInstallString;
end;

Function Do_UnInstall(sUninstallString: String): Integer;
var
  ri: Integer;
begin
  // Return Values:
  //  0 -> uninstall string = empty, new install?
  //  1 -> successfully executed UnInstallString
  // -1 -> error executing UnInstallString
  Result := 0;    // Default value
  if sUnInstallString <> '' then begin
    sUnInstallString := RemoveQuotes(sUnInstallString);
    if Exec(sUnInstallString, '/SILENT /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES','', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ri) then
      Result := 1
    else
      Result := -1;
  end else;
end;
Function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  case CurPageID of
  wpSelectComponents:
    begin
    if WizardSetupType(False) = 'del' then  // Uninstall and exit!
      begin
        OK2Unins := True
        if Do_UnInstall(sUnins) = 1 then
          Result := False;
          //ExitProcess(0);  This fails. Prompts user with a cancel message.
          WizardForm.Close;  // This trigger CancelButtonClick() code...
      end;
    end;
  wpSelectTasks:
    begin
    end;
  wpReady:
    begin
    end;
  end;
end;

Procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
// Predefined Wizard page identifiers
// wpWelcome =            1;
// wpLicense =            2;
// wpPassword =           3;
// wpInfoBefore =         4;
// wpUserInfo =           5;
// wpSelectDir =          6;
// wpSelectComponents =   7;
// wpSelectProgramGroup = 8;
// wpSelectTasks =        9;
// wpReady =              10;
// wpPreparing =          11;
// wpInstalling =         12;
// wpInfoAfter =          13;
// wpFinished =           14;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectComponents then
    Confirm := not OK2Unins;
end;
```

Comment: It depends on how do you imagine such options box. Do you want it to be the part of the wizard (e.g. on the modified welcome page) or could it be e.g. separate dialog with radio buttons displayed only if the program is already installed and which won't start the wizard if the user selects uninstall ?

Comment: Yes, I want it to appear on the initial welcome page. Since I will also run this from a command line in silent mode and I want the instructions for users to be simple. 3 choices only. You make a good point if this is initial install, then I can gray it out based on a code variable?

Comment: Yup, the best will be to read the `UninstallString` value from registry. If there will be such value, the program is installed, so you can keep those options visible (or enabled). That string might be handy also if the user chooses uninstall option, because it's the command line to execute uninstaller. I'll try to prepare a commented example. I'll be right back...

Comment: Thanks! Piecing more together...I found code for the Uninstall string and found in the manual that setting Return := False will exit setup, but still missing the Event to stick all this in? I need the Uninstall option to NOT create another unins000x.exe :)

Comment: It is too late to exit wizard from `InitializeWizard`, where you create those radio buttons. I'm thinking about skipping all the pages unless the `CurStepChanged` event will fire with the `ssInstall` step. In that stage you can call `Abort`, but I'm afraid it will pass you to the finish page reporting the setup failure. The `ExitProcess` Windows API function is strong enough, so maybe I'll just kill the process.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to avoid an entire custom form approach. What is the problem exiting setup immediately after running uninstall string in a shell?

Comment: I think that `ShellExec` of `UninstallString` followed by the `ExitProcess` Windows API function call from `NextButtonClick` event method sounds fair enough. I'm not a fan of process killing, but it seems there's no peaceful way to exit wizard without going to the finish page.

Comment: Cool, I will wait for your snippet to try. Thanks!

Comment: You can use UninsHS to provide these options.  But I don't know why you're trying to do anything weird regarding privileges -- just set `PrivilegesRequired=admin` (which is the default) and the installer and uninstaller will elevate to admin permissions themselves.

Comment: Incidentally, the trick I use for wizard early-exit is simply to disable the Next button, thereby forcing the user to click Cancel.  And if this is for a "normal" early exit (as opposed to an error) then change the caption on the cancel button to Finish and use CancelButtonClick to skip the confirmation prompt.  Of course, either way the exit code returned to the parent will be an error value.  You can't change that this way.

Comment: @Miral - I thought I was clear. Users do not have admin privileges so they cannot run uninstall from their Start Menu. UAC blocks any elevation requests. Setup/Uninstall must run from the proxy server! While UninsHS looks good, it is proprietary and I prefer to roll something simpler.

Comment: Sorry for a lack of my promised example, but either I'm busy or not at a computer where to build and test. I'll try to do it as soon as I'll be able...

Comment: If you want to install for users that do not have admin permissions, then you should be installing without admin permissions, in places that those users are able to write to.  There are standards for this sort of application.  Don't try to bypass UAC, that's just one of the signs of malware.

Comment: @Miral - Please think harder before posting. The proxy server is in place ONLY for installations and is running as admin! This allows icon creation and registry entries, or uninstallation of previous versions. Upon completion of install, the elevation is complete and the user can only execute the newly created app.

Comment: @TLama - Thanks for your replies. They sent me in the required direction. The setup.exe can now achieve all 3 options. I did have to scour more code than expected. A simple ExitProcess(0); failed since it triggered a NextButtonClick() event.

Comment: @skywalk - I did think and I'm well aware of what you're doing.  I'm just saying that at best it's a potential security hole, and will require exceptionally careful programming to avoid being exploited by malware.  As it's so very easy for that sort of thing to go wrong, it's usually best to not do it at all.

Comment: @Miral - For completeness, I will answer a last time. The customer locked down ALL users. Without proxy, NOTHING can be installed. My setup.exe does not request admin, since the proxy elevates for me. While I am new here, you are not and the terms of commenting are clear. Be constructive or upvote/downvote.